# Adding textfield to tablecells in the backend C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, html-table, textfield

I'm adding table rows (with 5 table cells) to a table after a click on a button. The code underneath works fine, but I'm struggling to make those tablecells textfields. So somehow I should put inside a tablecell the following:

```
<input type="text" id="rol_totaal" runat="server" class="tbl_input"/>
```

Any ideas how I can implement this in the following function? I'm working with C# in ASP.NET.

```
public void BtnAddCost_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


    var row = new HtmlTableRow() {  };
    var cell1 = new HtmlTableCell() { Height = "25px", InnerText="extra cost" };
    cell1.Attributes.Add("class", "title_kost_tbl tbl_border_bottom");
    var cell2 = new HtmlTableCell() { InnerText = "test 2" };
    cell1.Attributes.Add("class", "grey_bg");
    var cell3 = new HtmlTableCell() { InnerText = "test 3" };
    cell1.Attributes.Add("class", "grey_bg");
    var cell4 = new HtmlTableCell() { InnerText = "test 4" };
    cell1.Attributes.Add("class", "grey_bg");
    var cell5 = new HtmlTableCell() { InnerText = "test 5" };
    cell1.Attributes.Add("class", "grey_bg");
    row.Cells.Add(cell1);
    row.Cells.Add(cell2);
    row.Cells.Add(cell3);
    row.Cells.Add(cell4);
    row.Cells.Add(cell5);
    cost_tbl.Rows.Add(row);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Think you should be able to do something like this, however I've not had an opportunity to test it as I'm away from my computer:

```
public void BtnAddCost_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var row = new HtmlTableRow() {  };
    var cell1 = new HtmlTableCell() { Height = "25px", InnerText="extra cost" };
    cell1.Attributes.Add("class", "title_kost_tbl tbl_border_bottom");
    var cell2 = new HtmlTableCell() { InnerHtml = "<input type=\"text\" id=\"rol_totaal1\" runat=\"server\" class=\"tbl_input\"/>" };
    cell1.Attributes.Add("class", "grey_bg");
    var cell3 = new HtmlTableCell() { InnerHtml = "<input type=\"text\" id=\"rol_totaal2\" runat=\"server\" class=\"tbl_input\"/>" };
    cell1.Attributes.Add("class", "grey_bg");
    var cell4 = new HtmlTableCell() { InnerHtml = "<input type=\"text\" id=\"rol_totaal3\" runat=\"server\" class=\"tbl_input\"/>" };
    cell1.Attributes.Add("class", "grey_bg");
    var cell5 = new HtmlTableCell() { InnerHtml = "<input type=\"text\" id=\"rol_totaal4\" runat=\"server\" class=\"tbl_input\"/>" };
    cell1.Attributes.Add("class", "grey_bg");
    row.Cells.Add(cell1);
    row.Cells.Add(cell2);
    row.Cells.Add(cell3);
    row.Cells.Add(cell4);
    row.Cells.Add(cell5);
    cost_tbl.Rows.Add(row);
}
```